# Id Of List View in android

Tags: android, listview

```
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="324dp" />
```

This is the code of  list view in my application. I want to change the id of my list view in the entire project. How can I do that! i picked the demo project on listview from net.
now i want to change the id of listview. When I changed the id of the listview it gives an error. I did all the research but I could not find a solution. 
So help me out.

Comment: Its giving error because in demo project your activity is ListActivity. For that you need android:id="@+id/android:list" only.

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: your activity is list activity so this is only id you can give for listview

Comment: @ShreyaS, Your comment should have been an answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your ListView tag as below to avoid the error.

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="324dp" />
```

Comment: Dont use + in id. If you want to use, you can integrate like this.android:id=@+id/list or android:id=@android:id/list.

Comment: I want to make an object of ListView like this       ListView lv=findViewById(R.id.);    but I am unable to find the id! the id is not shown in the box!

Comment: ListView lv = getListView(); This will give you the object of ListView

Comment: @rajkaushal do it as Sweety Suggested or elese change your id as android:id="@+id/lv" and then create object as ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);